# do you use Heroku to write Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, heroku

do you use Heroku to write Ruby on Rails app?  i read about from the book Learning Rails from O'Reilly, and then today found that http://heroku.com/myapps doesn't have a "Create App" on the page so that I can edit the code online any more.  Do they only allow that for the paid user?  It also seems that they only let you have one web request at one time if you are a non-paying customer.

Comment: why not just use mod_rails and capistrano?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku has moved to a paid for platform (without the web-based editor). I guess you control it via terminal using the heroku gem.

However, all the old heroku functionality is available on http://herokugarden.com

If you had an account on heroku before herokugarden, all your apps should have been migrated there. You should be able to log in using your old id.

Comment: what is the difference if my app if running on heroku vs herokugarden?  is it due to different opinion of operations that the site splitted?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku has two offerings.
Heroku Garden - http://herokugarden.com - is the first product.  It includes an online IDE, and the ability to deploy your application.

In January Heroku launched a new platform, called "Heroku".  It drops the IDE, and in exchange provides significant stability and performance enhancements.

Heroku has a free offering.  As your app scales, or needs additional resources you can purchase what you need.  The free version can actually get you surpringly far - a single dyno is running my personal site right now (http://zednine.com) with no problems.

-- I am a heroku employee

Answer (score 0):

No particular difference, if you're just running in development mode. The two sites are still operated by the same company. Heroku is their commercial offering, with paid hosting plans, etc. Herokugarden is, if you will, the playground for people to play with rails and learn the framework before they move up to a paid plan.